# Excel hang while copying data from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

The Excel hang if the user click the button in the sheet. The button allowed the user to run the following VBA code. If the user runs the code from VBA editor, it's working fine. Kindly help. The code is as the following. I'm trying to copy data from current excel file to the other excel file newly created.

```
Sub clickBreak()
i = 12
Dim workBookName As String
Dim workBookName2 As String
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim pasteStart As Range

workBookName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName

workBookName2 = Insert(workBookName, "_2", InStr(workBookName, ".xls") - 1) & ".xls"
MsgBox workBookName2

Dim xlobj As Object
Set xlobj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

xlobj.CopyFile workBookName, workBookName2, True
Set xlobj = Nothing
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=workBookName)

Set pasteStart = [A12:A15]
wb1.Sheets("contents").Range("A12:A15").Copy
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=workBookName2)
wb2.Sheets("contents").Range("A12:A:15").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
wb2.Save

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`clickBreak` is not an event handler. If the name of your button is Break you must name the sub 
`BreaK_Click()` for it to act as an event handler for the button click event:

```
Sub BreaK_Click()
...
End Sub
```

Full Code:

```
Sub BreaK_Click()
i = 12
Dim workBookName As String
Dim workBookName2 As String
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim pasteStart As Range

workBookName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName

workBookName2 = Insert(workBookName, "_2", InStr(workBookName, ".xls") - 1) & ".xls"
MsgBox workBookName2

Dim xlobj As Object
Set xlobj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

xlobj.CopyFile workBookName, workBookName2, True
Set xlobj = Nothing
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=workBookName)

Set pasteStart = [A12:A15]
wb1.Sheets("contents").Range("A12:A15").Copy
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=workBookName2)
wb2.Sheets("contents").Range("A12:A:15").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
wb2.Save

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer

```
Sub clickBreak()
 Dim workBookName As String
   Dim workBookName2 As String
   Dim wbTarget            As Workbook
   Dim wbThis              As Workbook
   Dim strName             As String

   Set wbThis = ActiveWorkbook


   strName = ActiveSheet.Name

    workBookName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName

    workBookName2 = Insert(workBookName, "_2", InStr(workBookName, ".xls") - 1) & ".xls"

    Dim xlobj As Object
    Set xlobj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    xlobj.CopyFile workBookName, workBookName2, True
    Set xlobj = Nothing



   Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(workBookName2)


   wbTarget.Sheets("contents").Range("A1").Select


   wbTarget.Sheets("contents").Range("A12:A15").ClearContents


   wbThis.Activate


   Application.CutCopyMode = False


   wbThis.Sheets("contents").Range("A12:A15").Copy


   wbTarget.Sheets("contents").Range("A12:A15").PasteSpecial


   Application.CutCopyMode = False


   wbTarget.Save


   wbTarget.Close


   wbThis.Activate

   'clear memory
   Set wbTarget = Nothing
   Set wbThis = Nothing


End Sub
```

Thanks you for spending time on my question and giving feedback. Sorry for answering my own question, I just want to share my resolution with the other who will be having the same problem.
I got reference from this http://en.kioskea.net/faq/24666-excel-vba-copy-data-to-another-workbook